# Python regex findall not printing all

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am attempting to parse the following string

```
content = "ACC=OFF,Latitude = 01 15 30.20S Longitude = 036 47 10.83E,Speed = 0.00Km/h,Odometer = 36.477Km,2014-05-05,05:54"
```

As follows:

```
print re.findall(r'([\w\.-]+)=([\w\.-]+)', content)
```

The output is:

```
[('ACC', 'OFF')]
```

But the expected output should be:

```
[('ACC', 'OFF'),('Latitude','01 15 30.20S'),('Longitude','036 47 10.83E'),('Speed','0.00Km/h'),('Odometer','36.477Km').......]
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: -1 `content` is not a valid python thing

Comment: Isn't there any `,` between the `Lattitude` and `Longitude` fields?

Answer (score 5):

Remember whitespace and `/`:

```
In [13]: re.findall(r'([\w\.-]+)\s*=\s*([\w\.\s/-]+)', content)
Out[13]: 
[('ACC', 'OFF'),
 ('Latitude', '01 15 30.20S Longitude '),
 ('Speed', '0.00Km/h'),
 ('Odometer', '36.477Km')]
```

As you can see, `Longitude` is not recognized because it is taken to be a part of the `Latitude` value.

Comment: This doesn't match the given expected output - maybe because of an OP's omission, maybe not...

Comment: @Robin True. But if a) Values can contain whitespace and b) whitespace is used to separate pairs, it is impossible to do what the OP wants.

Comment: I'd settle with "annoying" instead of "impossible" (eg treating the `Latitude` case differently), but I thought the fact needed to be pointed out: the wanted output *is* weird.

Answer (score 2):

```
Latitude = 01 15 30.20S
```

There are spaces around the equal sign. Include this in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply your regex to:

```
content = 'ACC=OFF,Latitude = 01 15 30.20S Longitude = 036 47 10.83E,Speed = 0.00Km/h,Odometer = 36.477Km,2014-05-05,05:54'
print re.findall(r'(.*?)\s?=\s?(.*?),', s)
```

The problem your regex doesn't match all is because there are spaces around both your `=` and within the strings you want matched. The regex shown above will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

This gives the expected output as far as it is given in the question. (The `.....` in the end suggests that the date and time should maybe also be included, but how?)

```
>>> re.findall(r'([\w\.-]+)\s*=\s*([\d\.\s/-]*[\w./-]*)', content)
[('ACC', 'OFF'), ('Latitude', '01 15 30.20S'), ('Longitude', '036 47 10.83E'), 
 ('Speed', '0.00Km/h'), ('Odometer', '36.477Km')]
```